# Issues with Context for React Native login

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have managed to get my login authentification working, but I am having an issue with the conditional navigator in App.js. If I log in using the LoginStackNavigator, I then need to refresh the app to be able to use the DrawerNavigator. I would like it so that as soon as I log in, App.js realises this, and takes me to the drawer navigator.

I've tried to use the Context API but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my **AppContext.js**

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const AppContext = createContext({
  isloggedIn: {},
  setLoggedIn: () => {},
});

export default AppContext;
```

Here is my **App.js**:

```
import AppContext from "./src/Component/AppContext";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isloggedIn: false,
    };
    this.loginStatusCheck();
  }

  loginStatusCheck = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@storage_Key");
    if (userToken) {
      this.setState({ isloggedIn: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isloggedIn: false });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider
        value={{
          isloggedIn: this.state.isloggedIn,
          setLoggedIn: this.setLoggedIn,
        }}
      >
        <NavigationContainer>
          {this.state.isloggedIn ? (
            <DrawerNavigator />
          ) : (
            <LoginStackNavigator />
          )}
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my **LoginScreen.js**:

```
import AppContext from "../../Component/AppContext";

const LoginCall = () => {
  const { setLoggedIn } = useContext(AppContext);

  return setLoggedIn(true);
};


export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  
login = async () => {
    const { email, password, confirmpassword } = this.state;
    console.log(email);

    axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8002/rest-auth/login/", {
        username: "username",
        email: "default@email.com",
        password: "password",
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.key);
        this.storeKey(response.data.key);
        LoginCall;
      })
      //.then(this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen"))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  storeKey = async (value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@storage_Key", value);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error" + e);
    } finally {
      console.log("done");
    }
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          paddingTop: 40,
          alignItems: "center",
          flex: 1,
        }}
      >
  
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.login()}>
          <Text>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you're not importing axios on LoginSreen.

Try to add `import axios from 'axios'` with others importations

Comment: Ah I am actually importing it, I just didn't include it in this code sample sorry!